# Convert DateTIme to Date / "int is not allowed" error

Tags: sql, datetime

I've searched and searched - found variations on the theme, but no real answer to my problem.

I need to convert the `MAX` of a `datetime` to `date`, and insert it into a new table I've created.

Here's my code:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OptOutEmails]([emailaddressid],[FirstOptOutDate], [LastOptOutDate], [bu_id], [brand_id])
SELECT [dbo].[DistinctEmailIds].[emailaddressid] as email
,[dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[bu_id]
,[dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[brand_id]
, CONVERT(datetime, max([emailaddresses_summary].[FirstOptOutDate])) AS FirstOptOutDate
, CONVERT(datetime, max([emailaddresses_summary].[LastOptOutDate])) AS LastOptOutDate
FROM [dbo].[DistinctEmailIds] 
JOIN [dbo].[emailaddresses_summary] 
ON [dbo].[DistinctEmailIds].[emailaddressid] = [dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[emailaddressid]
WHERE [dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[LastOptOutDate] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY [dbo].[DistinctEmailIds].[emailaddressid],[dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[bu_id],[dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[brand_id];
GO
```

It needs to go into this table:

```
[emailaddressid] int not null PRIMARY KEY
, [FirstOptOutDate] datetime null
, [LastOptOutDate] datetime null
, [bu_id] int null
, [brand_id] int null
```

The error message I get: Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Line 56

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

I've tried everything I can think of. The resultant `CONVERT` statement in my code is from a string I thought would resolve this. Nothing is working. Please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the error because you've got the column order wrong; the columns in the insert statement doesn't match the order in the select statement:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OptOutEmails]([emailaddressid],[FirstOptOutDate], [LastOptOutDate], [bu_id], [brand_id])
SELECT [dbo].[DistinctEmailIds].[emailaddressid] as email
,[dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[bu_id]
,[dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[brand_id]
, CONVERT(datetime, max([emailaddresses_summary].[FirstOptOutDate])) AS FirstOptOutDate
, CONVERT(datetime, max([emailaddresses_summary].[LastOptOutDate])) AS LastOptOutDate
```

You want this:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[OptOutEmails]([emailaddressid],[FirstOptOutDate], [LastOptOutDate], [bu_id], [brand_id])
SELECT [dbo].[DistinctEmailIds].[emailaddressid] as email
, CONVERT(datetime, max([emailaddresses_summary].[FirstOptOutDate])) AS FirstOptOutDate
, CONVERT(datetime, max([emailaddresses_summary].[LastOptOutDate])) AS LastOptOutDate
, [dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[bu_id]
, [dbo].[emailaddresses_summary].[brand_id]
```

Also, you might want to change the aggregate columns to

```
, MAX(CONVERT(datetime, [emailaddresses_summary].[FirstOptOutDate])) AS FirstOptOutDate
, MAX(CONVERT(datetime, [emailaddresses_summary].[LastOptOutDate])) AS LastOptOutDate
```

as that conveys the intent better, and applies the MAX aggregate function to the converted datetime column instead of whatever it was before (varchar maybe?).

Comment: Hi guys - thank you so much! LOL - I added the columns in hindsight, what a noob (noobs anyone???) mistake! Beyond that though, I was then getting the Clustered Index error (my database is in Azure - another important piece of information.) But I didn't want emailaddressid to be the PK, so I created and ID using the AUTO_INCREMENT code in the table...'CREATE TABLE OptOutEmails
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
, [emailaddressid] int not null 
, [FirstOptOutDate] datetime null
, [LastOptOutDate] datetime null
, [bu_id] int null
, [brand_id] int null
);
GO' then, it worked like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The fourth column bu_id is of type int

Convert is doing conversion to datetime, so you are getting the error

```
 , CONVERT(datetime,    max([emailaddresses_summary])
```

You can convert it into int, which will return number of days since jan 01, 1900
Or you need to define your column as datetime

Same issue with brand_id column

```
, CONVERT(int, max([emailaddresses_summary])
```